# Steam Client Error -130: Unknown Error, could not connect to the page

Tags: steam, technical-issues

Okay, this happened completely all of a sudden. This morning, I was getting the "`-130`" error message even more than normal. That's the one that says

```
Unknown Error, could not connect to the page
```

I was also unable to update any of my games. I tried:

- restarting my computer and internet multiple times
- I then decided to completely uninstall Steam, not just everything excluding the `/SteamApps` folder, there was no trace of steam on my computer afterwards.
- I then re-downloaded the steam setup file.

The installation of Steam completed, but now that it's time for steam to do the "Checking for updates" stuff that the Steam installer itself does. Every time I try to finish the download, I get an error message that says

```
Steam needs to be online to continue. Please confirm your network connection and try again
```

My internet is completely fine. I can even access steam by using my internet browser, I can get to Google, Facebook, Youtube, so my internet is not a problem. I've closed, then opened my ports, disabled my firewall, disabled my anti-virus.

Also, if this helps, I tried doing a security scan with McAfee, which, apparently requires me to be connected to the internet, and it couldn't get to the internet either.
At the time, I was also still on Facebook, and Google, etc.

Comment: If McAfee also couldn't connect to the Internet, this doesn't sound like a Steam specific problem. And, just to be sure, you did post this question from that computer, right?

Comment: I just added the mcaffe thing as a side note.

Comment: And yes, I did this from the pc with the problem

Comment: Your firewall is probably to blame. Try turning it off, and see if that resolves the problem. If so, you'll need to open a hole in your firewall for the applications.

Comment: I did. That didn't work, either.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or something?  All indications show that your network is working correctly, but that specific services are blocked.

Comment: How do I check if I have a proxy? I'm not even entirely sure what a proxy is.

Comment: This is drifting into PC tech support and I think would be better served on superuser.com.

Comment: There is also some malware that prevents anti-virus software from properly getting updates. Maybe someone or something tampered with your hosts file?

Comment: @Schwern According to SU's guidelines it's not a good fit their either as it's essentially impossible to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Here is [a Steam forum discussion about error 130](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2613482) including [how to troubleshoot it](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?s=9500880ae35069d758334291a28dd917&p=29967872&postcount=6).

It's also possible you got nailed by [a recent botched Windows patch](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2859115/microsoft-windows/microsoft-releases-silver-bullet-patch-kb-3024777-to-eliminate-botched-patch-kb-3004394.html) which has been causing many problems.  Make sure you have all Windows updates installed.

Steam has a number of troubleshooting articles you should follow.

- [Using a Firewall with Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2198-AGHC-7226).
- [Troubleshooting Network Connectivity](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1456-EUDN-2493)
- [Using a Router with Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6776-MYXU-0480)

I highly suggest you follow the basic troubleshooting instructions to determine if it's your router: plug your computer *directly* into your modem and see if you still have the problem.  If you don't, it's your router.